# Searching within svn logs and merging several revisions at once

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

I want to be able to search within the commit logs of svn. I know you can do that on tortoise.
We are moving to a two-tiered repository approach, so that the stable branch will only get fully completed and tested stories. To achieve that, I would need a way to search within the commit messages for the story code (eg:#s1322) and get a list of the revisions to be used in a subsequent merge command.

Ex: searchsvnapp http://[repo location root] #s1322

result:
4233,4249,4313

This would then be copied and pasted in a merge command that would allow to apply all the revisions at once.

BTW, Is there any way to use the merge command to apply several revisions at once?

Thanks
Emerson

Comment: ...and the question is...? (tip: "how do I do it" is not something you should ask here. StackOverflow is for specific problems and questions. do your research, try to write some code, then return if you have something specific...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the command to apply several merges at once in sequence is:

svn merge http://subversion/svn/repository -c 228,245,251,254

Answer (score 1):

Sounds reasonable. The search part could be implemented with a script around the command line svn client, reading the output of "svn log", or "svn log --xml". You could even use an XSLT stylesheet in the latter case. The "--limit" option is worth using, so you save time by only searching comparatively recent commits.

The answer to your BTW question is "svn merge -c 4233 -c 4249 -c 4313".